# use root cmd window to execute commands in new cmd window

Tags: cmd

i'm trying to make a batch script for running my Java files. I've found out that there is no way to prevent auto-closure of a batch script(except using pause keyword, tho it just waits for key press). I've also discovered that starting a new window will cause only main windows to close, not the new one too so i want a way that the command `SET /P file=Java file:` is executed in the new window(I got the new window by using the `start` keyword. Is there any way to accomplish this without downloading other softwares? this is the code i came up with yet:

```
cd "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\Desktop\Files&Folders\HMMMMM\programs\java programmes"
set /P file=Java file to execute:
java %file%^.jar
start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking for that :

```
cd "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\Desktop\Files&Folders\HMMMMM\programs\java programmes"
start cmd /V:ON /K "@set /P "file=Java file to execute: " && java -jar !file!^.jar"
```

**EDIT:** Using expansion with /V and use of /K instead of /C to keep the cmd windows open.

Explanations : To launch a console process in another windows and keep it open after the end of this process console we launch another `cmd` process with the `start` command.  We use `/V:ON` to use delayed expansion by default, meaning modified variables (like the one we prompt, `%file%`) will be expanded on the fly with `!` (so `!file!` instead of `%file%`). We use `/K` to tell to this cmd process to not close when provided commands end. To this `cmd` process, we provide the following commands :

1. `@set /P "file=Java file to execute: "`

   This one will ask for the jar filename (without extension) to launch.
   The `@` means "do not echo the command itself on the console stdout" for a nice display.
2. `java -jar %file%^.jar`

This one launch the java  interpreter (JVM) with the filename of a jar file to execute through the `-jar` parameter, filename build from the previous prompt and  the `.jar` extension. The `^`  here escapes the `.`, it seems not useful here but maybe your script/env requires it.

We link the both commands with `&&` which means : _if left command from `&&` is successful (it exits with `ERRORLEVEL 0`) then execute the right command from `&&`.

Comment: it worked tho the other bat file auto closed and didn't even let me see code execution results

Comment: @Dev Then `start cmd /K "@set /P "file=Java file to execute: " && java -jar %file%^.jar"` is what you look for ? (/K instead of /C)

Comment: i would recommend u to edit ur main  answer too cuz i m gonna accept it

Comment: @Dev The answer has been edited with `/K`. I  added  `/V:ON`  which will made sure that delayed expansion is ON (and does not depend then from the parent script). `%file%` become then `!file!` to be sure to use the expanded value from the prompt. I guess the provided explanations are clear ?

Comment: i understood ur code tho um i got some new code which i just can't under stand how to apply into the code u gave, so it would be cool if u somehow fit this code in the same way so that the cmd window behaves totally same like before tho excutes this code:

`:loop
set /p file=Java file:
java %file%
goto loop `